# How to get flexibility in laravel sql query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a sql filter `where('comment_id', '=', 1)` to php code

```
$datas = $this->model->ADD HERE->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
```

Trying to add the string to code take me hours. How to make it?

---

Here is my code:

CommentResource.php passing the sql filter as string parameter.

```
<?php
class CommentResource extends BaseResource
{    
    public function index()
    {
        $filter = "where('comment_id', '=', 1)";
        return parent::index_filter($filter);
    }
```

CommentResource.php

```
<?php
class BaseResource extends Controller
{
    protected function index_filter($filter)
    {
        $datas = $this->model->ADD HERE->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
        return view($this->resourceView.'.index')->with('datas', $datas);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to use different types of where as filters in your queries. That's why you want to make them dynamic. I would suggest the following solution for your task:

```
<?php
class CommentResource extends BaseResource
{    
    public function index()
    {
        $filter = [ 'operator' => 'where', 'args' => ['comment_id', '=', 1]];
        return parent::index_filter($filter);
    }

<?php
class BaseResource extends Controller
{
    protected function index_filter($filter)
    {
        $where = $filter['operator'];
        $args = $filter['args'];
        $datas = $this->model->$where(...$args)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
        return view($this->resourceView.'.index')->with('datas', $datas);
    }
}
```

However, it will work starting from Php5.6+ because of oeprator `...`

Comment: It works, and that is what I want. Thank you. I consider changing the title more accurate. May I have your advice?

Comment: After days tried, I have some improve on the answer of @Andrej. In short, $filter is grown to nest array, and '...$args' is changed to $args. I'll post these codes in my answer, and try to explain the reason I change '...$args'.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your requirements correctly, but if you rewrite index_filter to accept `field` and `value` separately, then you may user a regular `where()` from laravel:

```
protected function index_filter($field,$value)
  {
    $datas = $this->model->where($field,$value)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
    return view($this->resourceView.'.index')->with('datas', $datas);
}
```

You can find the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions). In case you really need more flexibility:

```
protected function index_filter($filter)
  {
    $datas = $this->model->whereRaw($filter)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
    return view($this->resourceView.'.index')->with('datas', $datas);
}
```

Have in mind though that this is really dangerous, as you expose the possibility to inject malicious code, it should be definitely properly escaped beforehand.

Comment: Thank you. But I want more flexibility than just 'where'.

Comment: `whereRaw ` is a way to solve my question. 

In detail, pass `$filter = 'comment_id = 1';` to `index_filter($filter)`. Then in the method, `$datas = $this->model->whereRaw($filter)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(15);`, and it works.

Because I have no experience on inject prevention, I will study for a while, then I hope can discuss with you.

Comment: If query flexibility is availalbe in programming-time and not available in runtime, will it be safe from injected?@MatFiz

Comment: @zhang_career As long as youuse the function internally (i.e. the `$filter` value is hadcoded, not derrived from user input), you are safe to use it. You should just remember to sanitize user input: if for example you ask user to provide `comment_id`, then make sure to allow only integers etc. I am glad I helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @zhang_career pls at least upvote my answer if you find it useful :)

Comment: plz let me explain why I accept another answer. As far as I tried, whereRaw can only represent where in SQL, while self-defined array can represent more keywords. Am i right? And... the upvote you said, I am afraid my reputation < 15, so after upvoted, I cannot see the number more than 0. I'll try later.

Comment: @zhang_career no problem, I am glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

My latest code works right. I'll post here.

```
<?php
class CommentResource extends BaseResource
{    
    public function index()
    {
        $options = [
          'filters'=>[
                       [ 'operator' => 'where',
                         'args'     => [
                                         [ 'article_id', '=', $article_id ],
                                         [ 'comment_id', '=', $comment_id ],
                                         // add filter args...
                                       ],
                       ],
                       // add filter operators here...
                     ],
          'sorts' => [
                       'column'     => $sortColumn, // change sort column...
                       'order'      => $sortOrder,  // change sort order...
                     ],
                   ];
        return parent::index_filter($options);
    }

<?php
class BaseResource extends Controller
{
    protected function index_filter($options, $number=15)
    {
        $result   = $this->model;
        foreach ($options['filters'] as $filter) {
            $operator = $filter['operator'];
            $args     = $filter['args'];
            $result   = $result->$operator($args);
        }
        if ( $options['sorts'] != [] ) {
            $column   = $options['sorts']['column'];
            $order    = $options['sorts']['order'];
            $result   = $result->orderBy($column, $order);
        }
        return $result->paginate($number);
    }
}
```

The reason I change ...$args to $args is, when 'args' has more than on value, for example,

```
                 'args'     => [
                                 [ 'article_id', '=', $article_id ],
                                 [ 'comment_id', '=', $comment_id ],
                                 // add filter args...
                               ],
```

...$args will change 'args' to one array, but $args will remain 'args' as nest array, which is the operator 'where' want.